# Fold converts all CR and CRLF to LF?

Tags: osx, printing, newlines

I'm working with an old printer that expects CRLF as line-ends. Some of the text that I am printing does not have regular line-ends, and the obvious solution seems to be `fold` (or more precisely, `fold -s`). However, when I do this the printer advances a line without resetting the carriage to the left -- in other words, it prints as though it has been sent LF without the needed CR.

What is the best solution to this? Should I port the output of `fold` through `tr` before printing? My efforts along these lines have been unsuccessful, either having no effect or producing a variety of different garbled line-ends. Failed example:

```
cat exampleCRLF.txt | fold -s | tr "\n" "\n\r" | lpr -P PrintAdapter
```

This is under OS X, and I think the shell is BASH, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a decent solution in

```
cat example.txt | fold -s | awk 'sub("$", "\r")' | lpr -P PrintAdapter
```

Answer (score 1):

`fold` on Mac OS X 10.11 does not convert CR to LF:

```
$ perl -E 'say(("aaaa "x17)."\r") for 1..2' | hexdump -C | grep 0d          
00000050  61 61 61 61 20 0d 0a 61  61 61 61 20 61 61 61 61  |aaaa ..aaaa aaaa|
000000a0  61 20 61 61 61 61 20 61  61 61 61 20 0d 0a        |a aaaa aaaa ..|
$ perl -E 'say(("aaaa "x17)."\r") for 1..2' | fold -s | hexdump -C | grep 0d
00000050  0a 61 61 61 61 20 0d 0a  61 61 61 61 20 61 61 61  |.aaaa ..aaaa aaa|
000000a0  61 61 20 61 61 61 61 20  0a 61 61 61 61 20 0d 0a  |aa aaaa .aaaa ..|
$
```

As even after the `fold` the `0d` (CR) are still present in the output; `fold` has merely inserted `0a` (NL) where necessary.

If the input does use Internet linefeeds, and the printer does require Internet linefeeds, the cleanest way to call `0d` agnostic `fold` would be to convert the input to Unix linefeeds (delete any `\r` on the assumption these are next to `\n`), pass that output to `fold`, and then to convert the output of `fold` back to using Internet linefeeds:

```
tr -d '\r' < exampleCRLF.txt \
| fold -s \
| awk '{printf "%s\r\n", $0}' \
| lpr -P PrintAdapter
```

It may be more sensible to install `dos2unix` from a package system (Fink, MacPorts, Homebrew) and use that for linefeed conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `fold` seems to treat CR as whitespace.

Since the reason you have CR is that your output requires it, do your processing without worrying about CR, and normalize the CR characters at the end.

```
… | sed 's/\r//g; s/$/\r/' | lpr
```

This sed command removes all CR, then adds a CR at the end of every line. If your implementation of sed doesn't support `\r`, insert a literal carriage return (^M) character instead.

---

`tr` does a byte-for-byte translations, not a string substitution, so `tr "\n" "\n\r"` doesn't make sense. (The spurious character `\r` is ignored.) Use a tool like sed to perform a string replacement.